# Running an executable that is inside the project

Tags: c#

I have an exe application with i's required file and I've imported them into my VS C# project. I need to start the .exe process which is fine but I can't seem to get the path correct. Is there a way to reference local paths such as in html?

My visual studio solution structure:

```
/RendererProxy
/Application
  /COMTEST.exe
/core
/Program.cs
```

I'm trying to get from Program.cs to COMTEST.exe basically.

Comment: local to what?, the exe folder, current working directory?

Comment: @Sayse sorry, I wasn't clear. I've added my .exe to my solution project in VisualStudio. From a class in the root folder I'm trying to start the process running. I've put the directory layout of the visual studio solution in the origional post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
String exePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),"AIRApplication", "COMTEST.exe");
```

The above code resolved 1/2 of the issue. The other 1/2 was that the exe was not being copied to the debug folder. Updating the 'Copy to Output Directory' option resolved this.

Comment: I've tried that from a number of posts on here. It's not giving me the correct path. I have the exe inside a folder in the project called "AIRApplication" and it's called "COMTEST.exe", it works fine if I use the full location from the C drive but obviously when this is moved onto a new computer it won't work.

Comment: That's giving me the path:

"C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication1\\ConsoleApplication1\\bin\\Debug\\AIRApplication\\COMTEST.exe"

But the exe is in:

C:\Users\SPARKOL04\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\AIRApplication\COMTEST.exe

So it's not actually in the bin :S

Comment: You are having two issues. One is the path which my code fixes. The other issue is that the exe is not being copied to the debug folder. To enable this, select the COMTEST.exe within the solution, go to properties and select 'Copy Always' from the 'Copy to output Directory' option

Comment: Perfect thank you I've got it finding the .exe file now. The exe has a few files it needs that are inside a small folder structure. Is there anyway to put this same setting on for all of those files as well?

Comment: Just select them all in the solution explorer, go to properties and select 'Copy Always' from the 'Copy to output Directory' option as before

Comment: Life saver, thanks Chris. I've not had to do this before, thanks for the quick responses!